# Error : why starting docker-container on Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, docker

I recently update my Kubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10. Before that everything was working properly. Now When I run `docker-container up --build`, I receive this error message:

```
Building api
Step 1/5 : FROM node:6.9
 ---> cde8ba396275
Step 2/5 : MAINTAINER test@gmail.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 985d0e4808a4
Step 3/5 : ADD . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fd0439d10d5
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 374d1fbec8b8
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"cgroup\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/59881badec0b0100ca71e44f76f393cdab831786ec39b557bf5a4710c1f6b5ae/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/sys/fs/cgroup\\\" caused \\\"no subsystem for mount\\\"\""
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"cgroup\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/59881badec0b0100ca71e44f76f393cdab831786ec39b557bf5a4710c1f6b5ae/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/sys/fs/cgroup\\\" caused \\\"no subsystem for mount\\\"\""
```

Any idea what is going on?

thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works for me:
have a look a this: [github post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28109).

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Replace `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes"`
3. Update and restart: restart `sudo update-grub && sudo reboot`

for me, this worked. 
hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to version **17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu** using *17.04 Zesty* repositories. Seems that **17.10 Artful Aardvark** docker repository is not available yet.

Steps are:

1. Edit */etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list* and add:

   `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable`
2. Then update docker to  itslatest version:

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade docker-ce`